# Transliterate Removal of Symbols

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, transliteration

I am trying to transliterate ®, ©, ', and ™ into blank characters meaning completely removing them when they are slugified.

The following is what I tried to do:

```
var tr = require('transliteration');
var slugify = require('transliteration').slugify;

// replacement attempt
tr("0xAE, 0xFEFF"); // ®
tr("0xA9, 0xFEFF"); // ©
tr("0x2122, 0xFEFF"); // ™

slugify(name, { lowercase: true })
```

For example, when I use slugify on a name like "ABC®: 123", it transliterates to:

`abc-r-123`

However, I want the resulting name to be like:

`abc-123`

Comment: AFAIK, `0x...` sequences don't have any special meaning in JavaScript strings. In any case, the library appears to transliterate those characters just fine. I you don't want then transliterated you should remove them before passing them to slugify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See following steps, how I did it:

```
console.log(tr("ABC ©")); //Output: ABC (c)

var test1 = "ABC®: 123©" //test input to see results

var regex = /\((r)\)|\((c)\)/g; //regex to remove ® and ©, update on desire

console.log(tr(test1).replace(regex,'')); //Output: ABC: 123

//now sluggify
console.log(slugify(test1, { lowercase: true, separator: '-' })); //Output: abc-123
```

Further working can be seen on [Github Here](https://github.com/zishon89us/node-cheat/blob/master/string/tranliterate.js)

Comment: works like a charm the way you did it. I added a few others i didnt want slugified:

`tr(name).replace(/\((r)\)|\((c)\)|\((tm)\)|®|©|™|'|ʼ/g, '');`

Comment: Wouldn't the code be easier to understand if you just removed actual characters from source string **before** transliteration?

Comment: what part of above code you find uneasy and where you think chars are not being removed?